# cant converting date format with moment js

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I want to convert `March 5th 2019` this format to `2019-02-28`.

```
moment(this.state.preferedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Used this code to do the task ,But its not working ,Getting the following message

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), 
>    How to do it with moment js

Comment: `March 5th 2019` is indeed not in RFC2822 or ISO8601 format, what is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

This warning message happens when you create a Moment from a string that's not in a supported ISO 8601 format see [this][1]  for a list of supported formats).

In this case, it looks like you tried to parse the string 27/04/2016, which is not an ISO format. You can parse this format without a warning if you tell Moment what the format is: `moment("27/04/2016", "DD/MM/2016")`. Alternatively, you can change the format of your input to match the ISO spec: moment("2016-04-27")

Also, doing `moment(new Date("27/04/2016")).format....` seems to work. But i think their are some issues in this approach, maybe related to locales etc.

You're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution - moment('March 5th 2019', 'MMM Do YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

In your code it should look like this -moment(this.state.preferedDate, 'MMM Do YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert it directly. You need to do it manually as follows

```
var month = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
var date = "March 5th 2019";
var temp = date.split(" ");
var output = temp[2]+"-"+month.indexOf(temp[0].toLowerCase())+"-"+temp[1].slice(0,-2);
```